# Are binomial coefficients $F_1$ analogs of $q$-binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-functions, field-with-one-element

This is a mostly philosophical question. Is it fair to think of usual binomial coefficients and their identities as an $F_1$ case of $q$-binomial coefficients and identities? Here $F_1$ is the field of one element.

Comment: Yes, I would say you can.

Comment: This is indeed a very philosophical question. They do count something that may be interpreted as something over $\Bbb F_1$: [Subsets are subspaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element#Subsets_are_subspaces)

Comment: See, for example, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407093.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is not only fair, but also often very useful. The analogy is that sets are like vector spaces over $\mathbb F_1$, so for example the analog of $\binom{n}{k}$ counting $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, is that $\binom{n}{k}_q$ counts the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb F_q^n$.

In lack of a rigorous theory of $\mathbb F_1$, this usefulness can be illustrated through numerous examples. Take for example the [Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem), which is an important starting point of extremal combinatorics. Even though writing down the analogous statement over $\mathbb F_q$ is very easy, by just interchanging subsets with subspaces, the proof turned out to be much harder (the first proof was due to Frankl and Wilson).

The only uniform proofs I know Erdos-Ko-Rado over all characteristics (including characteristic 1) are "geometric" in nature and were discovered much later. However I'm afraid this isn't particularly emphasized in the literature. For example I haven't seen anywhere explicitly mention the analogy between the method of "shadows" and the study of the relevant partial flag variety over $\mathbb F_q$. Still, I think this is a very fun example of interplay between combinatorics of sets and geometry over $\mathbb F_q$ that has produced non-trivial theorems.

Comment: Where would one look to see a uniform-in-characteristic-including-1 proof (of anything)?  I thought that the theory was still so much in flux that such uniformity would be very hard to come by.

Comment: @LSpice, I just meant a uniform proof for finite fields, that works when you "translate" it to $\mathbb F_1$.

Comment: Henry Cohn gives such a proof in the paper I linked to above (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407093).